# Calculus,Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Can anybody help me with the following question,
Use the method of Lagrange multipliers to find $\max$ and $\min$ values for
$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$   subject to the constraint $4x^2 + y^2 + 9z^2=36$.

I have 
$2x=\lambda8x.$(1)

$2y=\lambda2y$ (2)

$2z=\lambda18z$(3)

$4x^2 + y^2 + 9z^2=36(4)$

From the the second equation (2) I got $\lambda =1$, but in equation (3)I got $\lambda = 9$ how can this be possible. Is lambda different in each equation ?, I assumed it it was equal for each equation.

Comment: Can you please tell us what you have tried so far and/or where you are stuck? You can edit and add those details to the question!

Comment: what is the exponant of $z$ in $4x^2+y^2+9z^$?

Comment: Aren't you missing something in the constraint ?

Comment: From $(2)$, $\lambda=1$ **if** $y \neq 0$. If you take that into account in all other possible places, you will find several solutions.

Comment: I am getting all max points because of the function f(x,y,z) is all positive squares with no minus constant, is this possible?

Comment: f(x,y,z)=2, f(x,y,z)=9 &f(x,y,z)=36

Answer (score 2):

It will perhaps clarify the situation if we make a geometric interpretation of the problem.  The function  $ \ f(x,y,z) \ = \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \ $ is the "distance-squared" function in $ \ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ for distances of points from the origin.  The "constraint surface" is a triaxial ellipsoid centered on the origin with its own axes aligned with the coordinate axes.

Your "Lagrange equations" factor as  $ \ 2 \ x \ (1 - 4 \ \lambda) \ = \ 0 \ $ ,  $ \ 2 \ y \ (1 -   \lambda) \ = \ 0 \ $ , and $ \ 2 \ z \ (1 - 9 \ \lambda) \ = \ 0 \ $ .  While each of the variables has a zero solution, they cannot *all* be zero at the same time, since extremal points must lie *on* the constraint surface.  Setting only one of the variables at a time equal to zero gives us cross-sections of the ellipsoid in each of the coordinate planes, which does not determine extremal values of $ \ f \ $ for us.

The three different values of $ \ \lambda \ $ are suggestive, since we are dealing with a triaxial ellipsoid.  For $ \ \lambda \ = \ 1 \ $ , the equations become

$$ \ 2 \ x \ ( - 3) \ = \ 0 \ \  ,  \  \ 2 \ y \ \cdot \ 0 \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ 2 \ z \ ( - 8) \ = \ 0 \ \ , $$

which requires that $ \ x \ = \ z \ = \ 0 \ $ , but leaves $ \ y \ = \ 0 \ $ open to assume any value.  The constraint equation, however, tells us that $ \ 4  \cdot  0^2 \  + \ y^2 \ + \  9  \cdot  0^2 \ = \ 36 \ \Rightarrow \ y \ = \ \pm 6 $ .  So this value of $ \ \lambda \ $ corresponds to the endpoints of the longest axis of the ellipsoid and to the value for our function $ \ f(0, \ \pm 6 , \ 0 ) \ = \ 36 \ $ [this proves to be the maximum value for $ \ f \ $ ] .  By similar reasoning, we find that

$$ \lambda \ = \ \frac{1}{4} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ y \ = \ z \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ x \ = \ \pm 3 \ \ , \ \ f(  \pm 3 , \ 0,  \ 0 ) \ = \ 9 $$

and

$$ \lambda \ = \ \frac{1}{9} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ y \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ z \ = \ \pm 2 \ \ , \ \ f(  0 , \ 0, \ \pm 2 ) \ = \ 4 \ \ \text{[the minimum value]} . $$

The Lagrange-multiplier method locates points where level curves or surfaces of the function $ \ f \ $ are tangent to the constraint curve or surface (what it actually does is find points where the normal vectors are parallel or anti-parallel).  Since our "distance-squared" function has "spherical symmetry", it can have level surfaces with tangent points to the constraint ellipsoid at *three pairs* of antipodal points.  These are marked by the three values of the multiplier $ \ \lambda \ $ .

An analogous problem for an ellipse in the plane can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747420/simple-lagrange-multiplier-problem-not-working-out) .

Answer (score 0):

Easier: cross multiply the two gradients using the determinant method and equate the result with 0. You get xy=0=yz=xz. The candidates are (x,0,0),(0,y,0) and (0,0,z). Plugging it into the constraint you get (3,0,0),(-3,0,0),(0,6,0),(0,-6,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,-2). The last two give min, and the the middle two give max or check.

Comment: Thanks, the past exam paper says you have to use lagrange multipliers.

Comment: I , for some reason thought that a min value needed to be < 0